# leaflet location-filter example and draggable-resizeable rectangular area-select on a map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, leaflet

I need to select an rectangular area on a map and identify markers that fall within that area.
Ideally, rectangle should be draggable and resizeable.
I am not too particular about the mapping and Google or Mapbox or Leaflet would all work just fine.

I found location-filter for Leaflet (https://github.com/kajic/leaflet-locationfilter/), which does seem to do the job. However, I couldn't find simple example code that shows how to use it. It has been used on tripcode.com but it is hard to make anything out of what is going on.
Does anyone have any experience with location-filter? If so, can you please point me to simple example of how to use it?

Are there similar examples for other mapping services particularly google maps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

For my [bbox page](http://osmz.ru/bbox/) I've snatched two files: [SimpleShape](http://osmz.ru/bbox/Edit.SimpleShape.js), [Rectangle](http://osmz.ru/bbox/Edit.Rectangle.js) from *Leaflet.draw* plugin and fixed them for better usability. The code for the rectangle is simple:

```
var rect = L.rectangle([[59.9, 29.9], [60.1, 30.1]]);
map.addLayer(rect);
rect.editing.enable();

rect.on('edit', function() { console.log(rect.getBounds().getBBoxString()); });
```

For advanced things like centering the rectangle on screen, see source code for the page.

Comment: The code from "bbox page" does not work with Leaflet 1.0.0-rc.3. Is the code available on GitHub?

Comment: There is a branch of https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw that is supposed to work with Leaflet 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

When you are drawing the markers onto the map you will need to add them to some kind of an array which will contain the lat/lng pair of each marker.

You can use [Leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) to draw the rectangle and modify it to return top left and bottom right coordinates on mouse up. On mouse up you can go over the entire list and which elements fit inside that bounding box.

This solution is just an example, there are many ways you can do this.

Comment: Thanks Marko for the response. Actually, leaflet-locationfilter seems to already have an implementation of the functionality I need. It has been listed on the leaflet site as a plugin too. Rather than trying to solve the problem again (and that too with my limited understanding of Javascript), I was looking for a solution that I can integrate.

Comment: Not a problem. As I've said, this is just one way you can achieve what you wanted. If the answer suits, you can accept it.