# Re draw a rectangle in leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, leaflet

If I have a map and I draw a rectangle like this:
map.setView([14.378300, 24.904200], 5);

```
var tileLayer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 17,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
});
tileLayer.addTo(map);


var rectangle = L.rectangle([  [21.616579,  29.487305], [7.798079, 20.522461]]);
map.addLayer(rectangle);
```

But on another button click I want to re define (re draw) rectangle parameters in another form.
like this:

```
$( ".select" ).click(function() {
rectangle =  new L.rectangle([  [17.853290, 34.980469], [10.876465, 14.853516]]);
map.addLayer(rectangle);
});
```

Is this possible? Please, somebody help me :(

[MY JSFIDDLE is here](http://jsfiddle.net/y1nb7sow/#&togetherjs=Tmxt9h1aCL)

EDIT:

I tried to do it like this when I defined two rectangles, and I defined two an on event for the second one, but I get this error  `Uncaught TypeError: rectangle2.on is not a function` can you help me please?

```
var rectangle, rectangle2;
rectangle =L.rectangle([  [21.616579,  29.487305], [7.798079, 20.522461]]);
map.addLayer(rectangle);

rectangle.editing.enable();

// Every time we move the selected area, refresh data about the selected area.
rectangle.on('edit', function() { 
    onRectangleChange(this);
});
rectangle2.on('edit', function() { 
    onRectangleChange(this);
});

$( ".select" ).click(function() {
    rectangle.editing.disable();    
    map.removeLayer(rectangle);
    rectangle2 =  new L.rectangle([  [17.853290, 34.980469], [10.876465, 14.853516]]);
    map.addLayer(rectangle2);
    rectangle2.editing.enable();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You code is working, just insert the jquery
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js

and remove the layer before rotate `map.removeLayer(rectangle);`

```
$( ".select" ).click(function() {
map.removeLayer(rectangle);
rectangle =  new L.rectangle([  [17.853290, 34.980469], [10.876465, 14.853516]]);
map.addLayer(rectangle);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y1nb7sow/2/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Actually yes that's true, but I'm setting a new element, I want to make it resizeable like [here](http://osmz.ru/bbox/)  based on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23996848/6145033) . And, I did it  but when I do this reset on clicking,  the  event `rectangle.on('edit', function() { ...` is not working? I don't know why? Can you help me please

Comment: @HudsonPD I edited my question is any other way to do it like that? please help

Comment: rectangle2 it is just a empty var, you need call the edit function after the rectangle2 be created